# List Product URLs in Magento Enterprise

Tags: magento-enterprise, product-collection, indexing, product-urls, ee-1.14.0.1

I try to compile a list of all product URLs for a given store. Given `$productCollection` prepared with store, status and visibility filter, this is how it works in Magento CE:

```
$catalogUrl = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/url');

$select = $catalogUrl->getReadConnection()->select();
$select->from($catalogUrl->getMainTable(), array('request_path'));
$select->where('store_id = ?', (int)$storeId);
$select->where('product_id IN (?)', $productCollection->getAllIds());
$select->where('options IS NULL');
if (!Mage::getStoreConfig('catalog/seo/product_use_categories', $storeId)) {
    $select->where('category_id IS NULL');
}

foreach ($catalogUrl->getReadConnection()->fetchCol($select) as $requestPath) {
    $url = Mage::getBaseUrl('web') . $requestPath;
    // do something with $url
}
```

But how would you achieve the same in Magento EE, where the standard URL rewrite table is not used for products?

Is there a unified solution that works independent of the URL model in CE and EE?

Answer (score 1):

Checking Magento's sitemap module this is the same as CE so I'd probably work from there.

This part in `Mage_Sitemap_Model_Sitemap::generateXml` does the actual collection output on products

$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sitemap/catalog_product')->getCollection($storeId);
$products = new Varien_Object();
$products->setItems($collection);

```
foreach ($products->getItems() as $item) {
    $xml = sprintf(
        '<url><loc>%s</loc><lastmod>%s</lastmod><changefreq>%s</changefreq><priority>%.1f</priority></url>',
        htmlspecialchars($baseUrl . $item->getUrl()),
        $date,
        $changefreq,
        $priority
    );
    $io->streamWrite($xml);
}
```

`Mage_Sitemap_Model_Resource_Catalog_Product::getCollection` returns a query in the `catalog/product` table so adding your WHERE conditions shouldn't be an issue either. The collection is already filtered on *visibility*, *store* and *status*.

Comment: Clever idea, but unfortunately it returns only one URL per product, without the category path. I need all of them, if "Use Categories Path for Product URLs" is configured.

Comment: @fschmengler hmm, okay, that's a challenge. I'll take another look during lunch :)

Comment: Thanks! I'm currently trying out what I can do starting with `Mage::getSingleton('catalog/factory')->getProductUrlRewriteHelper()->getTableSelect()` which I found in the sitemap resource model

Comment: It's harder than expected. The index tables only contain the product URL key. During request matching the URL is split at the last `/` and two separate lookups are made for category request path and product request path.