# Magento 1: how to make an extension EE compatible?

Tags: magento-1.9, module, magento-enterprise, extensions, magento-1

So here's the thing I never had the chance to get my hands on a Magento EE.

That said I still **would like to make my extensions EE compatible.**

Let's say we're dealing here with a normal CRUD module.

I'm looking for a **canonical answer on how could I achieve that specially regarding FPC and indexing. (And more maybe ?)**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I fear, that is way too broad for a canonical answer. At least you certainly cannot expect a checklist to follow without actually having to test your extensions in EE.

So get your hands on a copy and test:

1. Full Page Cache. Turn it on and see if everything still works. Test with multiple sessions in parallel.

   To exclude blocks from the Full Page Cache, learn about **hole punching** with `cache.xml`:

   - [removing a template from the cache](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/74376/removing-a-template-from-the-cache/74377#74377)
   - [what do cache.xml in etc folder of any module?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/133412/what-do-cache-xml-in-etc-folder-of-any-module)
2. URL indexing. If you interact in any way with the URL index, you will need to rewrite that, because EE replaces the implementation completely. For example not all URLs are stored explicitly in the database anymore:

   - [List Product URLs in Magento Enterprise](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/83144/list-product-urls-in-magento-enterprise)
3. Add to cart by SKU. If you do anything related to adding products to the cart, make sure that it also works with the "add to cart by SKU" form on the cart page.
4. Password hashing. If you are dealing with customer passwords (for example, custom import), be aware that EE uses a different hashing algorithm.

This list is by no means complete, just first thoughts from my experience. Will update when more comes to mind.

Comment: Let's say in a case of a normal CRUD module. Thanks for that btw I really appreciate

Comment: Did you ever write a "normal CRUD module" ? ;)

Comment: lol you got me here